# Changing the format of a Date Picker

Tags: c#, datepicker

I have a date picker (`DateTimePicker`) in my application. Currently, when a user selects the desired date, the outputed result reads as follows:

Code:

```
private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string date = startDatePicker.Value.ToString();
    dateStart.Text = date;
}
```

Output (what dateStart becomes)

```
07/16/2012 1:18 PM
```

However, I need the date to be formated like this:

```
2012/07/16
```

Also, I don't need the time to show up. Is there a way to change the date format and stop the time from showing up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use custom format

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx

Comment: Thats way to simple. Now I feel stupid. Thanks for the answer :)